# java.lang.noclassdeffounderror: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable nothing helped me

Tags: java, android, dalvik

I have such activityclass code:

```
package com.pavel.exchanger;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;


public class SearchExchangerActivity extends FragmentActivity   {
    static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
    static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
    private GoogleMap map;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_exchanger);

        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
            Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
                .title("Hamburg"));
            Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(KIEL)
                .title("Kiel")
                .snippet("Kiel is cool")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

            // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));

            // Zoom in, animating the camera.
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_exchanger, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

and such layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SearchExchangerActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and such manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pavel.exchanger"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.pavel.exchanger.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.pavel.exchanger.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.pavel.exchanger.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.pavel.exchanger.ExchangerListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_exchanger_list" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.pavel.exchanger.BankExchangersListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_bank_exchangers_list" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.pavel.exchanger.NbrbActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_nbrb" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.***"
            android:value="****" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.pavel.exchanger.SearchExchangerActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_search_exchanger" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

but when i run my activity  i get:

```
04-30 17:25:35.926: E/AndroidRuntime(400): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-30 17:25:35.926: E/AndroidRuntime(400): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
04-30 17:25:35.926: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
04-30 17:25:35.926: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
04-30 17:25:35.926: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:279)
04-30 17:25:35.926: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
04-30 17:25:35.926: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
04-30 17:25:35.926: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
04-30 17:25:35.926: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
04-30 17:25:35.926: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
04-30 17:25:35.926: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
04-30 17:25:35.926: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
04-30 17:25:35.926: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at com.pavel.exchanger.SearchExchangerActivity.onCreate(SearchExchangerActivity.java:26)
04-30 17:25:35.926: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-30 17:25:35.926: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
04-30 17:25:35.926: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
04-30 17:25:35.926: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-30 17:25:35.926: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
04-30 17:25:35.926: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-30 17:25:35.926: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-30 17:25:35.926: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-30 17:25:35.926: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-30 17:25:35.926: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-30 17:25:35.926: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-30 17:25:35.926: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-30 17:25:35.926: E/AndroidRuntime(400):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

i try to clean project, i added lib and project, i try to google and do some advices.... but nothing helped me(

What i'm doing wrong?

Note: i must run it on android 2.3.3...

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If I had to guess, when you "added lib and project", you added the JAR, not the Android library project. The Play Services SDK is an Android library project that happens to contain a JAR.

The [Play Services SDK documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) has the basic steps. Assuming that you are using Eclipse, you need to import the Play Services SDK Android library project into your workspace, then reference that library project from your app (Project > Properties > Android). Also, undo whatever you did originally to attempt to use the Play Services SDK, as that may interfere with the revised setup.

Comment: @brabertaser1992: I am going by your stack trace. The only way I can think of that would cause that exception is if you do not have the Android library project attached to your app's project.

Comment: @CommonsWare is right: the stacktrace has Dalvik looking for (but not finding) com.google.android.gms.R$styleable which would be a resource for the library. Try this: add a line like Object test=R.styleable; and see if Eclipse complains. It will tell you it doesn't know what styleable is, if your logcat is correct

Comment: java.lang.runtimeexception unable to start activity componentinfo

Comment: @CommonsWare:: Please look at my problem.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21677327/android-deletes-r-java-file-when-importing-google-play-services-lib