# Error with SupportMapFragment in Android Studio on a Fragment

Tags: android, google-api, android-studio, supportmapfragment, mapfragment

I have searched many hours and days to find the answer to this, but still cannot. I am using Android Studio (latest ver) IDE

I am trying to create a map view (using Google Maps API) into a Fragment that is part of a FragmentActivity.

AndroidManifest was updated with necessary permissions and Google Key.

As you can see at the output, LatLng class from Google Map API is working well as I am creating an instance.  Lib was imported on libs folder

Please help !!

***EDIT:*** Found this instructions
[How to build Google Play services (google maps) under Android Studio](http://www.orangedesk.info/blog/2013/06/08/how-to-build-google-play-services-google-maps-under-android-studio/)

**fragment_mapview_gmaps.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".ShowActivity" >

    <fragment
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MapViewFragment**

```
public class MapViewFragment extends Fragment {

    private static View view;
    private Context context;
    public static GoogleMap map = null;

    public MapViewFragment() {
        this.context = getActivity();
        loadMapFragment();
    }
    private void loadMapFragment()
    {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (view != null) {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            if (parent != null)
                parent.removeView(view);
        }
        try {
            LatLng sLatLng = new LatLng(37.857236, -122.486916);
            System.out.println("DEBUG: "+ sLatLng.toString());
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mapview_gmaps, container, false);
        } catch (InflateException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
            /* map is already there, just return view as it is */
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
     * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
     * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the app.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
        // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
        // a reference to the Tab.
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
            // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
            // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
            // this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                            .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
            /*Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;*/

            Fragment fragment;

            switch (position) {
                case 0: //List View
                    fragment = new ListViewFragment();
                    break;
                default: //Map View
                    fragment = new MapViewFragment();
                    break;
            }

            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 2 total pages.
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section0).toUpperCase(l);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**This is my output**

```
07-21 12:27:15.581    8768-8768/com.xxxx.cs.csitsclocator I/System.out: ListViewFragment.onActivityCreated
    07-21 12:27:15.581    8768-8768/com.xxxx.cs.csitsclocator I/System.out: ListViewFragment.onCreateLoader
    07-21 12:27:15.591    8768-8768/com.xxxx.cs.csitsclocator I/System.out: DEBUG: lat/lng: (37.857236,-122.486916)
    07-21 12:27:15.591    8768-8768/com.xxxx.cs.csitsclocator W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 1062 (MapAttrs) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$styleable;
    07-21 12:27:15.591    8768-8768/com.xxxx.cs.csitsclocator D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x000e
    07-21 12:27:15.601    8768-8768/com.xxxx.cs.csitsclocator D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    07-21 12:27:15.601    8768-8768/com.xxxx.cs.csitsclocator W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41003930)
    07-21 12:27:15.601    8768-8786/com.xxxx.cs.csitsclocator I/System.out: ListVewLoaderAsyncTask.loadInBackground
    07-21 12:27:15.601    8768-8768/com.xxxx.cs.csitsclocator E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
            java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:279)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at com.xxxx.cs.csitsclocator.TabMapView.MapViewFragment.onCreateView(MapViewFragment.java:59)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:461)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1064)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:911)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1432)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    07-21 12:27:15.621    1208-1208/? W/ActivityManager: Force finishing activity com.xxxx.cs.csitsclocator/.MainActivity
```

Comment: Have you added `google-play-services_lib` as a library?

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.noclassdeffounderror: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable nothing helped me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16305685/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-android-gms-rstyleable-nothing-helpe)

Answer (score 0):

> Lib was imported on libs folder

The Play Services SDK is an Android library project, not just a JAR. Remove the JAR from `libs/` and add a reference to the Android library project. That way, you will pick up the resources defined by that library project.