# Android 4.0 Issue with google plus login

Tags: android, google-oauth

I have google plus login working fine on devices > 4.1 but some devices cause a crash on 4.0
My best guess is that there is a issue(or it is outdated) with google play services installed on the device.

This is the error I get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{me.frankly/me.frankly.view.activity.NewLoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #103: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2077)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #103: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:608)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:682)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:741)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:744)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:744)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:491)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:254)
       at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1837)
       at me.frankly.view.activity.NewLoginActivity.onCreate(NewLoginActivity.java:112)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4479)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2041)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:588)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:682)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:741)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:744)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:744)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:491)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:254)
       at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1837)
       at me.frankly.view.activity.NewLoginActivity.onCreate(NewLoginActivity.java:112)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4479)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2041)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$drawable
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.q.b()
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.q.a()
       at com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.a()
       at com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.G()
       at com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.setStyle()
       at com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.<init>()
       at com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.<init>()
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:588)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:682)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:741)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:744)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:744)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:491)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:254)
       at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1837)
       at me.frankly.view.activity.NewLoginActivity.onCreate(NewLoginActivity.java:112)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4479)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2041)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going through your stack traces I noticed

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$drawable
```

That leads me to **assume** that you added the jar for the Play Services SDK but didn't add the Android library project and that is why it could not be found. It may also be possibility that you may be using an outdated version of the Play Service SDK.

I suggest viewing CommonsWare solution by clicking [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16305851/1371041)